# ReactJS update component by click on another component

Tags: reactjs

Hey I'm kind of new to ReactJS maybe I'm using the wrong approach but here's what i got.

I have 2 components "Course.js" and "WeekDays.js".

So my basic idea is I have a "weekly" calendar with dates of this week and a json API that returns courses based on the "weekly" date. this by itself works fine. but it doesn't seem to work when I try to change the state of the "day"

this is my **WeekDays** snippet

```
    state = {
      day: "",
    }

    handleClick = (e) =>{
        this.setState({day:e.target.id})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="WeeklyCalendar" className="row grid">

              <div id="Days" className="col-md-12">

                  <div className="row">
                    { this.state.weeks.map(WeekDays => 

                        <div id={WeekDays.DaysNumber} onClick={this.handleClick} className={`col ${WeekDays.Class}`} key={WeekDays.DaysNumber}>
                            <span>{WeekDays.DaysNumber}</span>
                        </div>

                    )}
                </div>

              </div>

              <div id="SideMenu" className="col-md-3">

                  <Courses value={this.state.day} />

              </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

And this is my Courses snippet

```
    state = {
        course:[]
    }

    getJson(){
        axios.get("?day=" + this.props.value)
        .then(res => {
            const course = res.data;
            this.setState({ course:course });
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getJson();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">   

                { this.state.course.map(course => 

                    <div className={`col-md-12 course_${course.id} `} key={course.id}>

                        {course.title}

                    </div>

                )}

            </div>
        );
    }
```

now as i said this works on its own, if i set `<Course value="16" />` it works, but it doesn't change the state when i do it with the onclick function

It works everywhere, but it does not re-render my component.
If i {this.state.day} inside the render function it works just fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: A good practice would be to also cancel your `axios` request when component is `unmounted`. Otherwise, if request takes longer than the lifetime of the component, when it completes you will try to `setState` on an unmounted component.

Comment: @Cristy how can i do that? or where can i read up on that, since I'm litreally just mashing code together and hoping for the best

Comment: This popped up as first Google result, but I didn't read it:  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-work-with-react-the-right-way-to-avoid-some-common-pitfalls-fc9eb5e34d9e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but what you can do is use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to call `getJson`.

The problem here is that you only call the function on `componentDidMount` and it won't be called again if `this.props.value` change.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
        this.getJson()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I'll be dammed was it really that simple...Where does "prevProps" come from?

Comment: @Innervisions I added the link to the docs. It's a lifecicle method of react.